# Parse Google map location using JSON Android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have a json file stored in my assets folder (map_location.json) i need to display map markers parsed from the json file.Here's my json file:

```
{
"Dine": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Place Name",
        "address": "Place Address",
        "lat": -33.867,
        "lng":  151.206
    }
]

}
```

Comment: There is built-in library in android for parsing the JSon.

Comment: i dont know how.can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to read JSON file from asset using bellow method:

```
public String loadJSONFile() {
String jsonStr = null;
try {

    InputStream is = getAssets().open("map_location.json");

    int size = is.available();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

    is.read(buffer);

    is.close();

    jsonStr = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return jsonStr;
}
```

Then you read returned jSON string using this code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFile());
JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("Dine");
ArrayList<Double> latList= new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> lngList= new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String> nameList= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> addressList= new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) 
{
    JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
    String name_value = jo_inside.getString("name");
    String address_value = jo_inside.getString("address");
    double lat_value = jo_inside.getDouble("lat");
    double lng_value = jo_inside.getDouble("lng");
    nameList.add(name_value);
    addressList.add(address_value);
    latList.add(lat_value);
    lngList.add(lng_value);
}
```

Comment: Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token MainActivity.java /jsonmap/src/com/example/jsonmap line 90 Java Problem

Comment: Please upload your .java file on http://textuploader.com/ and give me link of that file

Comment: pastebin.com is also banned on my system

Comment: Please find code from this link http://textuploader.com/kgzf and execute it if any problem let me know.

Comment: yes i will.but i have a problem,it only loads map ,how can i add marker using the map details on my json?

Comment: Please uncomment commented code from your file which I sent you

Comment: still have problem, heres my logcat error : http://textuploader.com/kuhc and heres my code : http://textuploader.com/kuhm

Comment: Please upload your map_location.json file

Comment: But the code which I sent you yesterday is properly working at my side without giving error?

Comment: can you send me the source file? if it work on mine, i will accept this answer

Comment: Please find working code at http://textuploader.com/kuxt this take some small changes

Comment: it shows plain map, no marker displayed.the coordinates on json are  sydney's location so the marker would appear on sydney.

Comment: can i send you my project file?

Comment: Please find this code http://textuploader.com/kuxc which contains some other modification.